# SSIS: Set list variables of (1) inventorycountNr and (2) StoreNr, and then use them in a where clause

Tags: ssis

1.Script Task: set arrays of (A) inventory count and (B) StoreNr
2.Data flow task: Use the list variables in where clauses (to filter and thereby speed up performance)

*Script task must read from server A and Data flow task from server B.
I dont want to use linked server and dont want to filter downstream the dataflow, but instead want to filter through the where clauses in the dataflow source (OLE DB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it in two Data Flows.

In first:

1. Select value to be used in where from source table
2. Store this values in string variable `ListToBeFetched` as comma separated list using Srcipt Component as destination witch code similar to:

```
using System.Text;
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    StringBuilder sb;
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        Variables.IdListToBeFetched = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if (!Row.Value_IsNull)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Row.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Do the same with second list.

In second Data Flow set dynamic generated query as sql command in `OLE DB Source` (taken from [Jamie Thomson blog](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/12/09/SSIS_3A00_-Using-dynamic-SQL-in-an-OLE-DB-Source-component.aspx)):

1. Create a new variable called SourceSQL
2. Open up the properties pane for SourceSQL variable (by pressing F4)
3. Set EvaluateAsExpression=TRUE
4. Set `Expression` to `"select * from table where columnToBeSearched in (" + @[User::ListToBeFetched] + ")"`
5. For your OLE DB Source component, open up the editor
6. Set Data Access Mode="SQL Command from variable"
7. Set VariableName = "SourceSQL"